Next.js Adding Third-Party JavaScript does not work
I am trying to convert my vanilla js project to a next project but i am having hard time importing the js files. For some reason it just does not work.
Here is the index.html(vanilla js working version)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Backgammon</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/min.css" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Darts Credits">
        <script src="build/js/top-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="game"> </div>
        <script src="libs/socket.io.js"></script>

        <script src="src/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="src/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="src/checker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="src/dice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="src/placeholder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="src/gameplay.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="src/preload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>controller.createGame();</script>
    </body>
</html>

This is just a simple phaser game. controller.createGame() loads it to the div and works fine.
Now here what i did on next js:
Project structure:

As you see i placed my .js files to public/game/src folder.
layout.js:
import "./globals.css";
import localFont from 'next/font/local'
const myFont = localFont({ 
  src: 'ilisarniq.ttf',
  weight: "800"
})




export const metadata = {
  title: "qwe",
  description: "asdasd",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="tr">
      <body className={myFont.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

page.js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const BackgammonComponent = dynamic(
  () => import("../app/components/BackgammonComponent"),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);


export default function Home() {

  return (
    <main>
      <BackgammonComponent/>
    </main>
  );
}

BackgammonComponent(where i am trying to load the scripts)
"use client"; // This is a client component 

import io from 'socket.io-client';
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Script from 'next/script'
import Head from 'next/head';




export default function BackgammonComponent() {

  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3000',{
      query:{
        "platform":"web"
      }
    });
    setSocket(socket);
    console.log(window.controller)

    
  }, []);


  return (
    <main >
    
    <Head>
<script src='../game/src/top-min.js'></script>
<script src='../game/src/controller.js'></script>
<script src='../game/src/global.js'></script>
<script src='../game/src/checker.js'></script>
<script src='../game/src/dice.js'></script>
<script src='../game/src/placeholder.js'></script>
<script src='../game/src/gameplay.js'></script>
<script src='../game/src/preload.js'></script>
<script>controller.createGame()</script>
     </Head>

      <div>Game component</div>
      <div id='game'></div>

    </main>
  );
}

nothing happens when i load the page.
What i expect is to work just like vanilla js/html version.
What is wrong here?

The .js files you're trying to import are in public folder. According to Nextjs documentation, the file public/game/src/top-min.js can be accessed by visiting the /game/src/top-min.js path. Example:
export default function BackgammonComponent() {
return (
  <main>
    <Head>
      <script src='/game/src/top-min.js'></script>
      // apply same path pattern for other <script> tag
      <script>controller.createGame()</script>
    </Head>
    <div>Game component</div>
    <div id='game'></div>
  </main>
  );
}

Furthermore, you can use Nextjs/Script component with prop strategy='lazyOnload' to optimize when additional scripts are fetched and executed.
import Script from 'next/script';
export default function BackgammonComponent() {
  return (
  <main>
    <Head>
      <Script src='/game/src/top-min.js' strategy='lazyOnload'></Script>
      // apply same path pattern for other <Script> tag
      <Script strategy='lazyOnload'>controller.createGame()</Script>
    </Head>
    <div>Game component</div>
    <div id='game'></div>
  </main>
  );
}

